# Guide for consul, why consul service takes more time then expected?

Tags: consul, service-discovery

I am in process of integrating discovery system. I am using consulate for python services and consul-api in java services. 
In my architecture i am requesting service each time before making request. **However it add 3-4milliseconds** to actual call. In place of catalog/agent api i am using health api to get healthy service instance and using further. 
I just want to the right way to do so and wanted to reduce this fetch time(3-4milliseconds). Please note that i am not using docker. Here is the code for fetching service.

```
    service = self.consul_client.health.service(service_id=service_id, passing=True)
    if not service:
        return None
    service = service[0]['Service']
    service_url = str(service['Address'])+":"+str(service['Port'])
    if "http" not in service_url:
        service_url = "http://" + service_url
    return service_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the additional latency is due to the API call you're making to Consul.. I can think of few ways to improve this -

1. cache the healthy urls and updated them periodically nor if a request fails (requires a retry mechanism)
2. use consul-backed client side load balancing libraries that already implemented it
3. use a consul-aware proxy, like https://linkerd.io/
4. use Consul's [DNS interface](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) and [DNS caching](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/dns-cache.html) (requires that your services will listen on known ports or the use of SRV DNS queries)